# Can't understand the use of resolvers in apollo-client

Tags: apollo-client

I'm a junior frontend programmer discovering apollo-client, with the apollo-boost bundle, to make a react app.

I'm following the [Apollo-Client tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state.html#resolvers) and can't understand the use of resolvers.

1) Why are they useful, since you must write a GQL query/mutation both in the resolver and in the component using the resolver?
They seem to add a redundant layer of complexity.

2) Is there a way to learn the resolvers syntax without diving deep into the graphQL backend? I'm looking for a kind of graph that shows something like

> "the GQL queries ask the **apollo-client** for a resolver function,
>   then the resolver makes the query to the cache,..."

Because I'm guessing a lot about how things work.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Looking at [this example](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/tree/master/examples/todo) is the easiest way to start understanding the apollo local state.

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." - [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)